# How is this lemma used?

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, homotopy-theory

The lemma is given below:

> [image]

And the use of is in the following line:

> [image]

Where $f'$ is the inverse of $f$, and $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $g: Y \rightarrow Z$.

I do not understand how this lemma is used in this line, could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: What book is this from?

Comment: It is in the solutions of Hatcher for problem 3 chapter 0 @NoahSchweber

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $f'$ is not an inverse of $f$ as a function, but as a homotopy equivalence; therefore, it is not true that $f \circ f' = 1_Y$ but rather $f \circ f' \simeq 1_Y$. The lemma then allows you to say that
$$ g\circ(f \circ f') \simeq g\circ (1_Y) = g, $$ and then that
$$ (g\circ(f \circ f'))\circ g' \simeq (g) \circ g' \simeq 1_Z.$$
The same holds for the second line.